# Can Flutter set system network proxy on iOS?

Tags: flutter

I want to make an iOS app to set socks5 proxy for global system. Just like set a vpn. Can this be achieved? I did not find any docs about network setting for Flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by writing your custom platform-specific code.

Reference: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Make it interact with native code on iOS and configure network settings from there.